# How to get data from nested relationship in Laravel 8 Eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

How to make a deep relationship with eloquent? I'm trying to display the data like this :

```
+------------------------------------+
| Main ID | Name  | SN  | Last Event |
|------------------------------------|
| 12      | James | j89 | RIGHT      |
+------------------------------------+
```

The "Last Event" column is based on the latest data on "Tracks" table but the value "RIGHT" is relation between the "Tracks" table with "Events" table. So, in this table, the latest record in the tracks table is id of 9 with `event_id` of 12, the `event_id` of 12 in the Events table has `name` column that contained value `RIGHT`. That value that I want to grab it to display in front end. this is my table in database.

```
Main table
+---------------+
|id | name | sn |
|---------------|
|12 | James| j89|
+---------------+

Tracks table
+-------------------------------------+
|id | main_id | event_id | created_at |
|-------------------------------------|
| 5 | 10      | 10       | 2021-10-12 |
| 9 | 10      | 12       | 2021-11-20 |
+-------------------------------------+

Events
+----------+
|id | name |
|----------|
|10 | LEFT |
|12 | RIGHT|
+----------+
```

If I use has one relationship with `latestOfMany()` method, it didn't reach to the events table. How do I reach it to the Events table to grab the value in Events table through the latest data of Tracks table based on main_id? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) to load deep in your relation, if you setup your relation correctly:

```
 class Main extends Model
    {
     public function latestTrack()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Track::class,'main_id')->latestOfMany();
    }
  }

class Track extends Model
{
 public function event()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Event::class,'event_id');
}
}
```

now you can get the structre you need:

```
$main=Main::with('latestTrack.event:id,name')->find(12);
```